# How to send an image to a view in jquery

Tags: javascript, python, jquery

I have the following html:

```
<form action="{% url 'change_avatar' %}" id="change-avatar-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="avatar" id="change-avatar-file" style="display: none;" />
    <label for="change-avatar-file" class="change-avatar">Change </label>
</form>
```

I am currently passing this to the view via a normal submit:

```
$('#change-avatar-file').on('change', function() {
    var form = document.getElementById('change-avatar-form');
    form.submit();
})
```

In other words, I"m just detecting the input change, but I'm still triggering the form submission. How would I pass this instead as an ajax call to my view? The only variable I need to pass is the "avatar", which is the `<input type="file">`. How would this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you don't really want to submit the form, you want to take the data and send it somewhere each time the users edits the input.

For that you can do something like this:

```
$('#change-avatar-file').on('change', function(e) {
    var input_value = $(e.target).val(); 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/views/my-view',
        data: {
        value: input_value
      },
      success: (data) => {
        // data = reposnse from server,
        // you can do whatever you want with it now
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.log('There was an error: ', err); 
      }
    }); 
});
```

If you sending the data to a view, you're likely getting HTML back as a response, at which point you can append it to the screen, or do what ever you want with it.